# Fixed-point digital ringing filter in C

Tags: c, signal-processing, avr, avr-gcc

I'm trying to code a digital ringing filter on an AVR microncontroller, and I am having some trouble with the implementation of the state diagram in fixed point arithmetic.  Here's a picture of the signal flow I am attempting to write code for:[image]

Edit: (I believe the equation for T_c above should be e^[-1/(F_s*D)] )

Here's what I have so far.  I have a routine called smultfix that does a fixed point signed multiply on two 8 bit signed integers and returns a 16 bit signed product.  F_c and T_c are 8 bit signed binary fractions.  "Output" and the intermediate step at the junction of T_c's input and the delay element, z1, are treated as 16 bit binary fractions.  So I have:

(assume F_c and T_c are defined elsewhere)

```
int8_t generateSample()
{
    static int16_t z1 = 0x7FFF;  //initialize first delay element to max positive value
    static int16_t output;
    int8_t byteOutput = 0;
    int8_t bytez1 = 0;

    bytez1 = (z1 & 0xFF00)>>8; //make z1 into an eight bit signed binary fraction for    
                               //multiplication

    output = (smultfix(bytez1,F_c)<<1) + output; //calculate output, shift product
                                                 //left once to 
                                                 //remove double sign bit

    byteOutput = (output & 0xFF00)>>8;          //generate output byte

    z1 = (-(smultfix(byteOutput,F_c)<<1)) - \
            (smultfix(bytez1,T_c)<<1) //generate intermediate                
                                                             //product z1
    return byteOutput;  
}
```

Unfortunately, I seem to have just created a poor random number generator, as this code generates a lot of garbage filling up my output buffer! If someone could point out where I might be going wrong, or if they have an implementation idea that would be better, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you shift the output of smultfix, you lose the sign bit.

Comment: @BrettHale If I'm treating both the multiplier and multiplicand as signed binary fractions, if I multiply them I get two sign bits, right? So I have to remove one,yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is actually correct - but the sign of the equation for T_c should indeed be *positive* rather than negative.  It's shown as being negative in the first edition of the book, and it seems that this image was taken from the *second* edition of the book, in which the equation was corrected.  If T_c is evaluated with a negative exponential, there will be increasing oscillations, but if it is positive the oscillations will decrease, which is what we want.  Having T_c negative and flipping the sign of the subtraction on the second to last line also works.